# Send to a friend form in popup

Tags: magento-1.9, product, send-mail

Is there any way to make send to a friend form in popup box in product view page i have tried with the default template code in "template/sendfriend/send.phtml" by directly copy in to a popup box but its seems to be error can anyone help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

First you need create a popup on the product page using the any of these library `jQuery`, `Bootstrap` or `Prototype js`.

After that include/call the `send.phtml` file on this popup content.

Comment: i'm tried to add like this but it seems to be the same error <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('sendfriend/send.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: Replace `sendfriend/send` instead of `core/template`.

Comment: i have also tried this but same result in error log i found this error "Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"

Comment: The problem resolved after i changed the setting from backend System -> Configuration. Under Catalog choose Send Friends and choose "IP Address" in "Limit sending to"!"    Now the email template is show but when i click on send mail there is nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

I use Fancy box for that

My Email to friend link looks like

```
<?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>

<li>
        <a class="feature first v-centered-content" rel="fancybox1" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?>">
        <span class="email-to-friend" > Email to a Friend</span>
    </a>
</li>

<?php endif; ?>
```

My fancybox popup init

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
    jQuery("a[rel=fancybox1]").fancybox({
    'padding': 0, 
    'type'    : 'iframe',
    'width'    : 700, // change the required width
    //'height'   : 700, // change the required height
    'height': 'auto',
    'overlayShow':false,
    'autoSize' : false
     });
 });
</script>
```

Remove Header footer from sendto friend page from layout

```
    <sendfriend_product_send>
        <reference name="root">
            <remove name="header"/>
            <remove name="footer"/>
        </reference>
    </sendfriend_product_send>
```

send button event after form fillup

```
jQuery('#send-email').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
        parent.location.reload(true); 
    }, 1000);

})
```

Comment: This method is not working foe me but i have created my own popup and include the send.phtml file  now i can see the form in popup but when i click on send mail there is nothing happen also there is no error in console

Comment: @Amith This all things based on your theme and how you implement this,  I have just give you idea about how you can achieve

Comment: iam using the base theme rwd in magento 1.9

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala - is it possible to use `'type' : 'popup'` instead of `'iframe'` here. Please answer me, as it will be of great help

Comment: @ManashviBirla, what is the issue with Iframe ?

Comment: it is just for the ease of designing, i wanted popup instead of iframe

Comment: @ManashviBirla for m1 or m2 ?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala - i am working in m2

Comment: Add `<block class="Magento\SendFriend\Block\Send" name="sendfriend.send" cacheable="false" template="Magento_SendFriend::send.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
            </block>` in page you want to show and add this block code in popup

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala - i will try and let you know. Thanks for your time. !!